# How to include Dynamic component presentation in the tridion page?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How to include/refer a dynamic component template in the page.  I had created a dynamic CT and published it, but want to render its presentation in the page.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to add dynamic presentation on the page.

Direct Approach - For this your component presentation should be allowed to on page. Check **Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly**. Add the presentation on page same as all others.

Code Approach - You may use API to get your component presentation direct from the broker storage.
Here is sample code for the same.

```cs
*<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent"%>
<%
  ComponentPresentationFactory factory = new ComponentPresentationFactory();
  ComponentPresentation ps = factory.getComponentPresentation("CompID","TEMPLATEID");
  Response.Write(ps.Content);
%>
JSP example:

<%@ page import="com.tridion.dynamiccontent" %>
<% 
  ComponentPresentationFactory cpf = new ComponentPresentationFactory("tcm:0-1-1"); // Publication URI
  // Component URI and Component Template URI
  ComponentPresentation componentPresentation = cpf.getComponentPresentation("CompID", "TEMPLATEID");
  out.println(componentPresentation.getContent());
%>
```

c#

```cs
ComponentPresentationFactory cp_factory = new ComponentPresentationFactory(publicationid);
ComponentPresentation cp = cp_factory.GetComponentPresentation(CompID, TEMPLATEID);
if (cp != null)
  {
     Output = cp.Content;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is multiple ways to show a **Dynamic Presentation** on a page:

- the most simple one is marking your **Dynamic CT** as `"Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly"`, then you will be able to embed it on your page as a Non-Dynamic CT

[image]

- For more advanced alternatives, you can check the Live Content Documentation: 
  [Implementing Content Delivery > Developing Web Pages](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=dynamic%2520component%2520presentation&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1349784679412&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_2CD03A3B6F88437D910CFC8FC7A6783D&query=&scope=&filename=DevelopingWebPages.xml&docid=concept_2CD03A3B6F88437D910CFC8FC7A6783D&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)