# change in component are not getting reflecting in the Page with Dynamic component Template

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have created a component Template and I made this component Template as Dynamic. I have checked "Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly". 
The output is of type "HTML fragment".

Then I published Component and Component Template.

I created a Page and added the component and its component Template to the Page. The output of the page is aspx.

The Page TBB is like this.

```
    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
             @@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I published the page. My published pages are getting stored at local location C:\Temp.

I opened the page through visual studio and browsed the page through IE.

Then I made changes to component and published it. The changes are not getting reflected in the published page. As the CT is dynamic, changes should automatically reflect in the page.

But it did not reflect.

Did I miss any steps?

**EDIT**

I cannot find

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" etc .../>
```

Do I need to do any setting in any of the config file.

Can anyone let me know reason behind this?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: First, check that you published the component from the correct publication. If you did, then please share the relevant section of the code from your published page. You should see a <tridion:componentpresentation> tag.

Comment: @DavidForster. I have published component from publication where my page resides. I cannot see <tridion:componentpresentation> tag in  my page source. Can you tell what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the language of your publishing target is not set to 'none'. The 'none' setting will force the publisher to embed the DCPs in the page, and prevent them from being dynamically included.

Comment: .DCPs are not getting published. I changed storage config file. Now I can DCPs are getting published. But I dont have Broker DB configured. Does it really affect DCP, Because my pages are not getting updated for any update in Component.

Comment: What is your target type's server side language set to?

Comment: .I just checked. It is set to "None". Can you tell, which ine to choose among the drop down.

Comment: That really depends on the server language you use on your web server. What is the extension of your pages?

Comment: I am using aspx Pages. So, I will choose ASP.NET as language

Comment: No.. even after updating the Language, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17879/discussion-between-chris-summers-and-user-222)

Comment: Thank alot Chris. I just followed your suggestion and Now I am able to see the <tridion:ComponentPresentation element. Can we directly browse this page under IIS. I have browsed it, but getting exception like"Unknown server tag 'tridion:ComponentPresentation".

Comment: For completeness - Please see this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855576/executing-a-page-with-dcp-in-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1

Answer (score 3):

Refer url 
[How to include Dynamic component presentation in the tridion page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799509/how-to-include-dynamic-component-presentation-in-the-tridion-page/12799717#12799717) to verify your approach.
after this if you feel any further assistance , let us know .

Comment: S. Thanks for your solution. As mentioned in the link referred, I have followed "Direct Approach - For this your component presentation should be allowed to on page. Check Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly. Add the presentation on page same as all others." Did I miss any thing here. Can you help me.

Comment: @Ram.. I am able to find Dynamic Component presentations on the published Items. But i could not find scripting tags related to DCP on the page. Can you help me here.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly are you able to locate your Dynamic component Presentation now? As you were having some issues yesterday.

Also verify your changes to DCP first and as @DavidForster suggested check if they published to same publication.

Hope all this will help you.

Comment: @Vikas.. Thank you for helping me yeaterday. Even after the changes suggested by you. I still cannot locate my DCP:(. I added the ItemTypes and etc. No LUCK:(

Comment: @User222 Provide us your full cd_storage file, I will locate DCP for you. Then you would be able to locate changes as well.

Comment: I had updated it yesterday in my question. Shall I update with the complete comments.

Comment: I just had a quick look on this, your DCP should go to C:\temp\data\ if you have restarted the ISS/related services. If not DCPs are in your Tridion CM database.

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting me. Though I changed the config file I reatrted the IIs but for to restart services. Now I can see component presentation data getting added. You really helped me alot. we dont have broker data base configured. So, I think the pages are getting updated with the script.

Comment: I am unable to find the scripting tags in my Page, Can you tell what might have gone wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17865/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-user-222)

Comment: As suggested by Chris, I have changed the Traget Language and restarted all services, then I am able to find DCP tags in my Page. Thanks for assisting me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you have the tag `<tridion:componentpresentation>` on your page source as already suggested. But make sure that you are checking the file source directly, **not the view / page source on your browser** as on your browser, this tag will be already rendered.

If you don't find it on your source, what are you finding? the rendered component presentation? If this is the case, your page is not retrieving the component presentation as a  DCP.

Can it be that you published your page before making your CT dynamic? if this is the case you need to republish the page.