# Executing a Page with DCP in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have published a ASPX page with DCP.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:9-5251-64" ComponentURI="tcm:9-5245" TemplateURI="tcm:9-5247-32"/> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

What are the ways to execute this page, so that it renders the DCP.

I just tried browsing this page through IIS, I am getting parser error.

```
Unknown server tag 'tridion:ComponentPresentation'
```

It would be great if some one can guide me to run this page.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have following tag in **web.config** and **Tridion.ContentDelivery** dll in bin

```
  <configuration>
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="tridion" 
     namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI"
     assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: you'll also need to have the storage configuration handy so the content delivery dlls know where to get the content from.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the 'API Server Role' for your .NET web application:

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_FF19F86A63E246F793D64495849EDEDF

(username/password required)